# A faulty printer doesn’t respond to ARP requests. How to spoof it from a Linux router?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arp

I have this silly printer that will answer to ARP only once in a while (relatively rarely, sometimes one has to wait 5 minutes to get a connection). However when I add its MAC manually to the ARP table on a client machine, it works very well (responds to ICMP pings, prints etc. instantly).

One solution could be to add it statically to `/etc/ethers` on each client machine. But this is probably wrong, as new machines won’t be able to learn about it in the future.

This local network is run by a Linux router.

Another solution would then be for that *router* (10.77.4.1) to respond to ARP requests directed at that printer (10.77.4.5). I read some manuals and thought it would suffice to just do this on that Linux router:

```
$ sudo arp -i wlan0 -s 10.77.4.5 f4:81:39:86:73:cb pub
```

… i.e. add a manual (*permanent*) and *published* entry, but it turns out that `pub` functionality never worked, after quick Google™’ing?…

I also thought of using `arping` or `arpoison` to broadcast this printer’s address, but they would have to do this constantly (say, every second), for stuff to work reliably. It would be better, if the router was only responding to *requests*.

How can I make it do that?

---

This is how it looks:

```
# arping 10.77.4.5
ARPING 10.77.4.5
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=0 time=250.435 msec
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
```

… and under the hood:

```
# tcpdump -i wlp8s0 -v arp
tcpdump: listening on wlp8s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:34:44.877417 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:45.878547 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:46.879713 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:47.880887 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:48.882064 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:49.883216 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:50.884338 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:51.134742 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 10.77.4.5 is-at f4:81:39:86:73:cb (oui Unknown), length 28
21:34:51.928209 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:52.886242 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:53.886689 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:54.887869 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:55.889023 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:56.890206 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:57.891361 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:58.892543 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:34:59.893485 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:35:00.894657 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:35:01.895783 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:35:02.896968 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:35:03.898118 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
21:35:04.899301 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.77.4.5 tell 10.77.4.100, length 44
```

Comment: The printer is Canon PIXMA MG6450 if anyone’s interested what not to buy. =D

Comment: Are there any firmware updates available for this printer? This might have been fixed.

Comment: That’s what I checked at the very beginning. It’s auto-updating and running the latest firmware. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this as an excuse to set up a CUPS server, as forcing ARP to work correctly in this edge case across the entire broadcast domain is more likely to cause confusion if there ever needs to be a future change of admin hands, or if networks need refactoring.

Not only can you consolidate your print management plane this way, but you can use CUPS as a central server for addressing, allowing you to focus any ARP fix on a single server. Printers that use various connection types can be represented with IPP or IPPS connections from CUPS, making client connection management much easier.

I'm not sure if this is your only printer in this environment, but even if it is CUPS is still a good solution to the issue. Some details on installation can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html

Comment: I will most probably do that, thank you! Seems to be a great idea. =] But first I had to win it my way, haha (see my answer). Now, CUPS on the router/switch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are looking at the wrong problem.  Is there the possibility that the printer is configured incorrectly?  If it had the wrong subnetmask, there is the possibility that something like this symptom would be manifested.

Also, what is the topology of the network?  It is strange that you talk about a router, but ARP is a layer 2 protocol.  Is the printer behind the router?  Is the router also acting like a switch with a few bridged interfaces?  Is there another switch involved?  Are the printer and clients all connected to the Linux server's wlan0?  What is the security set up like on the wireless network with client-to-client communication?

Comment: It could be configured incorrectly, yes, hmm, but would it then respond *somtimes* (as it does, see my answer and log in the question) or *never*?

Comment: And yes, I meant switch! Sorry. =) No other interfaces, just `wlan0`, netmask is configured; devices are configured via DHCP. This only happened with this printer. IP cameras and other computers respond fine.

Comment: As for `hostapd`’s config, here it is: https://github.com/michalrus/dotfiles/blob/3f83de4809c341f83e7bee81394125536321724e/nixos-config/machines/embedded/router-chwalecice/nat.nix#L75-L79

Answer (score 0):

While I love the accepted CUPS idea, what I did (because I’m stubborn and it should’ve been possible to do… :-\ Turns out it was) was hacking that out using this code: https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2007/11/spoof-an-ipv4-arp-response.html.

It will wait for a request and only then respond, effectively eluding client kernel’s protection of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_accept` being by default set to `0`.

The diff can be seen here: https://github.com/michalrus/dotfiles/commit/69e41b586a925bec4abf9d2a26d4e374bd6404bd — my mod just allows configuring which address to spoof.

The service runs on NixOS, so it’s really easy to configure: https://github.com/michalrus/dotfiles/blob/3f83de4809c341f83e7bee81394125536321724e/nixos-config/machines/embedded/router-chwalecice/printer-hacks.nix#L36. Underneath this definition, I also decided to ping the printer every two seconds, to keep it alive.

The result:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_accept
0

# arp -d 10.77.4.5

# arping 10.77.4.5                          
ARPING 10.77.4.5
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=0 time=2.770 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=1 time=354.998 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=2 time=1.980 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=3 time=2.050 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=4 time=299.506 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=5 time=2.060 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=6 time=2.143 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=7 time=348.676 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=8 time=5.234 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=9 time=1.990 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=10 time=294.930 msec
42 bytes from f4:81:39:86:73:cb (10.77.4.5): index=11 time=6.950 msec
^C
--- 10.77.4.5 statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 12 packets received,   0% unanswered (4 extra)
rtt min/avg/max/std-dev = 1.980/110.274/354.998/152.334 ms

# arp -n 10.77.4.5
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.77.4.5                ether   f4:81:39:86:73:cb   C                     wlp8s0
```

This `arping` got 4 extra packets with relatively long RTTs from that lazy printer; so it became more lively right now.

But things are working wonderfully now! Thanks, everyone.